# Buffer Incoming Data and put into S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

For a specific business requirement I need to batch up 5 minutes worth of data from AWS IOT to S3 and process the data.

1. I tried the firehose approach where I put data into firehose bucket
   and buffer it for 5 minutes (possible up to 900s). However this is
   only possible for limited volume of incoming records since once the
   size threshold (128MB) get satisfied firehose will not wait for 5
   minutes to write data into S3. Hence this is not scalable.

What are other ways to achieve this in AWS?

appreciate your input.

Comment: What will you be doing with the files after they are generated, and why is it not acceptable to have multiple files within a 5-minute period?

Comment: The classification job need least 5 minutes worth of data to output accurate results. Its possible to trigger a classification job on S3 put notification. However if firehose put multiple files in S3, there is manual process of merging them in to one file which can be real hassle in a large scale.

Comment: What is your actual data volume? Are you already processing > 128 MB in 5 minutes? If not, then I would recommend using Firehose until your overall process is proven, then substitute in an alternative.

Comment: Can you gzip the files before putting the data into firehose? In my case a 5 minute logfile was 11,560,268 and not 101,632,807.
Or use some filter making the files smaller (`cut -d";" -f1` of `grep "interesting"`)?

Answer (score 2):

**Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose** is convenient because it can accept an incoming stream of data and save it to Amazon S3. You are correct that the maximum buffer is **900 seconds** and **128MB**.

See: [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/limits.html)

It sounds like you are not happy with such limits and you would like a single file after 5 minutes, regardless of filesize. To accomplish this you would need to use a normal **Amazon Kinesis Stream with your own consumer** reading data from the stream. This is a fairly complex process and involves having Amazon EC2 instance(s) reading the data and copying it to S3.

It would be much easier to use Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose. Perhaps one option is to have Firehose output files at its normal limit intervals, but use something else to trigger the processing (or whatever you wish to do) every 5 minutes.